# JQueryui menu will not position properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am attempting to create menus dynamically using JQueryUI menu widgets.

[Plunker Example -- Dynamic Menu Creation with issues](http://plnkr.co/edit/bDdIse?p=preview)

The problem is that the menu is not positioning itself faithfully.
It (the menu) seems determined to always appear near the bottom of my html body
on the first click of my menu button click handler, and only on the second click of the menu button handler will it appear in the appropriate position, nestled to the bottom of my menu button. So, how do keep my menu faithful to the menu button which I intended?

[image]
[image]

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myTabs").tabs();

      var $replaceMenu=$("<ul style='position:absolute;z-index:9999;'>" + 
        "<li><a href='#'>Replace Current</li>" + 
        "<li><a href='#'>Replace All</li>"  +
        "</ul>").menu();

        var replaceMenuHandler=function(event){
            $replaceMenu.position({
                my: "left top",
                at: "left bottom",
                of: this
              })
              .on( "menuselect", function( event, ui ) {
                var selectedReplaceOption=ui.item.text();
                console.log(selectedReplaceOption);
                $replaceMenu.hide();
              }).show();
              event.stopPropagation();
        };

        $replaceMenu.appendTo("#testMenu").hide();
        $("#testMenu").on("click",replaceMenuHandler);

    });
```

Comment: I dont know if its the same issue... But I had the same issues with jQueryUI Autocomplete. It happens because jQueryUI uses a default html element to append its divs. If the element is not present it will append to the end of you html body. As of here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem was that setting position in the click handler for the menu (see replaceMenuHandler) is not a good thing. Once I removed the menu.position call from the click handler and only called it when I initially made the menu, the code begin workign as I intended.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bDdIse?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myTabs").tabs();

  var $replaceMenu=$(
    "<ul style='position:absolute;z-index:9999;'>" + 
      "<li><a href='#'>Replace Current</a></li>" +
      "<li><a href='#'>Replace All</a></li>" +
    "</ul>")
        .menu()
        .appendTo("body")
        .position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: "#testMenu"
          })
      .on( "menuselect", function( event, ui ) {
            var selectedReplaceOption=ui.item.text();
            console.log(selectedReplaceOption);
            $replaceMenu.hide();
          });

    var replaceMenuHandler=function(event){
        $replaceMenu.show();
    };

    $("#testMenu").on("click",replaceMenuHandler);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to set a style for `<button id="testMenu">`and set it to `position: relative;`

So go for something like that in your CSS:

```
#testMenu {
    position: relative;
}
```

Your .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a  will then also need:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
}
```

...then it will look good!